# How do I add an image to a visio template shortcut

Tags: visio

I've built a Visio Template (vstx) and saved it to my %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates folder.

It appears in Visio, when I choose the custom templates, but appears with a blank image.  I've got other custom templates that I've downloaded and placed in the same folder that show up with an image.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the image below to not be a white rectangle.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new drawing
2. Ensure "Save preview" is enabled (i.e. the checkbox is checked).
3. Draw (or insert) the picture you want to see as a preview in the drawing.
4. Save the drawing as template.
5. Set "Lock preview" flag
6. Remove the picture and save the template again (preview will be not overwritten)
7. Profit!

If you want a high-quality (high-resolution) previews, you could also consult this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chhopkin/2008/10/29/create-perfect-previews-for-your-templates/

NB: this seems to be offtopic for stackoverflow.